# Android Map intent not loading full URL

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

My android app has this code to catch links clicked with a google maps address

```
if (url.contains("https://www.google.com/maps/"))
            {
                Uri mapURL = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapURL);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
```

This works as expected and loads google maps app, the problem is the addresses are breaking at the first comma. So for example if the link was

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=13 fake street, 
fake country&destination=13 fake street, fake country&travelmode=driving
```

I have tried urlencoding the clickable link with no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Just use `%20` instead of space.